# Будет ли запускаться программа на более старых версиях JRE?

Tags: java

Программа написана с использованием JDK 8. Будет ли она работать на более старых версиях JRE (3, 5 или 6)?

**Оригинальный вопрос:**
Написана программа на java для windows 7.
вопрос будет ли работать если на компьютере стоит например java 5 а на др. java 3 или 6?

Comment: Это зависит от того, под какую версию Java программа была "собрана". Для этого используется ключ компилятора.

Comment: hinotf, собрана в 8 версии.
а на том в котором будет использоватся 6 5 и 3

Answer (score 3):

Должна быть использована та версия JRE, под которую программа и была скомпилирована, либо можно использовать JRE более высокой версии (поскольку обычно обеспечивается практически полная обратная совместимость).

Вот список ссылок из документации про возможную обратную несовместимость:

- [Java SE 8 vs Java SE 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999198)
- [Java SE 7 vs Java SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities)
- [Java SE 6 vs Java SE 5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html#incompatibilities)
- [Java SE 5 vs Java SE с версии 1.4.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137462.html#incompatibilities)